# Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I have a Maven Project with Apache Camel.
Source Code Here: https://github.com/GauravBhandari19/myDevCodePUBLIC/tree/master/maven/Mongo

When I try to run Java: App.java file

[image]

I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]
Offending resource: class path resource [application-context.xml]

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
```

Can anyone please help me why I am getting this error, else someone who has already integrated Camel(3.2.0) with Mongo which I can refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a missing depy in pom.xml. I added Camel Mongo suggested entry and I did not encounter this issue. However I changed the method of connecting to Mongo, I am now connecting route to class component and in the class used Mongo Client. Code update on my GITHUB Folder. :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use XML Camel config like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


    <mongo:mongo-client id="myDb" host="${mongo.url}" port="${mongo.port}" />
</beans>
```

you need to add

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

to the pom.xml - please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference for more details

Example of the camel route

```
 <camelContext id="test" 
                  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route autoStartup="true" id="CronQueryMongo">
            <from uri="quartz://test?trigger.repeatInterval=2&amp;trigger.repeatCount=1"/>
            <setHeader name="CamelMongoDbCriteria">
                <constant>
                    {"_id":1}
                </constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="mongodb:myDb?database=meteor&amp;collection=msg&amp;operation=findAll"/>
            <transform>
                <simple>${body.toString()}</simple>
            </transform>
            <to uri="stream:out"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```